# Force fluent migrator to keep running even after failure

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

Is it possible to make FluentMigrator continue execution even if a failure occurred such as a foreign key conflict? The reason i am wondering is because one of our migrations relies on an ID that is created only after all migrations are over in our DevProfile. As such it will always fail due to FK conflict.

I was wondering if it were possible to force it to run anyway even after a failure?

Answer (score 0):

This may be worth reading: https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator/wiki/Transaction-modes-for-the-migration-runner

I don't believe that what you are asking for exists.